# FileNotFoundException in HttpRequest every second time

Tags: java, android, network-programming

In my android app, i want to let the user fetch data from a website (by sending an http request). The http-response is then sent to another activtiy which shows the data. (i made this a bit simplier in this example code. In real, the data is parsed into an object and the object is sent).

This all works good with my code. But when the user goes back to the main activity by pressing the back key, and trys another request, the application throws an `java.io.FileNotFoundException` while getting the input stream from the URLConnection. If the app is closed (by pressing back again) and then reopend, all works well again.

Im pretty sure its a problem with a connection not being closed properly or something like that but i cant find the error in my code.
Any idea whats wrong here?

MainActivity.java

```
*no interessting code here.
it just calls the static function from MainMethods.java
when a button is pressed*
```

MainFunctions.java - I want to call the methods from several classes so its in an extra class

```
class MainFunctions {

    public static void search(final Activity, final String searchString) {

        new AsyncTast<String, String, String>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // im opening a progress dialog for the activity here
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... searchString) {
                try{
                    return new HttpUtils().sendRequest(searchString)
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // print a dialog, stacktrace and stuff
                    return null;
                }
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if(result != null) {
                    // dismiss the dialog etc..
                    Intent i = new Intent("packagename");
                    i.putExtra("key", result);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }
           }           
        }.start(searchString)
    }
}
```

HttpUtils.java

```
public class HTTPUtils {

    public String sendRequest(String data)
        throws IOException {

     String answer = "";

     URL url = new URL("http://myURL.com/" +  data);
     URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
     conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 conn.getInputStream()));

             String inputLine;

     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
         answer += inputLine;

     in.close();

     return answer; 
}
}
```

The Stacktrace shows that the Exception is thrown while `conn.getInputStream()` is called.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myURL.com/danijoo
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.elophant.utils.HTTPUtils.sendRequest(HTTPUtils.java:20)
at com.elophant.Elophant.getSummoner(Elophant.java:183)
at com.lolsummoners.datacollector.Collecter.getSummonerInfo(Collecter.java:39)
at com.lolsummoners.utils.MainFunctions$1.doInBackground(MainFunctions.java:106)
at com.lolsummoners.utils.MainFunctions$1.doInBackground(MainFunctions.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

The Methods `getSummoner()` and `getSummonerInfo()` are methods to parse objects out of the response string. i let that out to make the problem easier to undearstand.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the stack trace ?

Comment: What is HTTPUtils.request() doing?

Comment: @smk This was a typo. HTTPUtils.request() was meant to be HTTPUtil.sendRequest() - i edited it.

Comment: @Quanturium just in that moment the server i get my data from went down :/ As its not my server i have to wait until it gets up again to produce the stacktrace..

Comment: Are you sure this was not the server having issues ?

Comment: @Quanturium server is up again.
I thought about this beeing a server issue too, but the error is 100% reproduceable. It only and everytime occures after switching back to the first activity and do another request. For example i can still do the request from the second activity after i did a request from the first one. When i kill the app and reopen it i can also do a successfull request. Only on going back to the first activity the error occures.

StackTrace is now in my first Post!

Comment: Nevermind. I got it! Really stupid issue comming from bad programming style. I got the data to send via http request from an EditText and by pressing "Enter" an OnKeyListener called the Methods. Somehow the "Enter-Code" was also put in the edittext box as an invisible "%A0" and wasnt deleted when the second activity started. After going back, i sent the EnterCode %A0 with the searchString to the server which caused the error. Next time ill post the complete code ;)

Comment: Could you please mark this topic as solved ?